# How do I high-five Dartrix in Pokemon Refresh in Pokemon Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

So before I allow my Dartrix to evolve into his final form, I want to be able to high-five him like I've been hearing so much about.

I can't figure out how to for the life of me. I've tried holding the cursor above his head, shaking it, everything I can think of.

What do I do?

Comment: I believe for all Pokemon that can you hold down the cursor just to the left hand side of them, but I'm not confident enough to post it as answer. Try it and get back to us.

Comment: I haven't tried it with Dartrix, but with my Pikachu I had to put my hand next to his.

Comment: Whoops! Thought I replied. Doesn't seem to be working for Dartrix. A video of someone demonstrating where to hold to high-five Dartrix would be very, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the cursor for a second or two near where the pokemon's hands or front feet are, and they will get the idea and try to high five you.

Source: Just tested in game, the "tap above head" method didn't work

Answer (score 0):

From [this Polygon article](https://www.google.com/amp/www.polygon.com/platform/amp/2016/11/21/13681686/pokemon-sun-and-moon-high-five-pokemon-refresh?client=safari):

> The Pokémon Refresh feature encourages trainers and Pokémon to bond through petting, feeding and some casual play. **That includes the exceedingly adorable high-five, which is triggered with a player taps the screen with their stylus right above a willing Pokémon’s head.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem. Let me say it like this, middle and final evos can't high five for some reason. Besides arcanine, no other evos can high five as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Not all pokemon can high five. One of the NPCs in the game (I think it was a breeder in a pokemon center, but I cant remember. I KNOW there is one, though) states that some pokemon can high five you. SOME. Not all.